# Is it possible to instruct the browser not to render/reflow/update the viewport during asynchronous DOM manipulations?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, dom-manipulation, html-rendering, reflow

I have something like this:

```
async function async_DOM_manipulations(){
    await DOM_manipulation_1() ;
    await DOM_manipulation_2() ;
    await DOM_manipulation_3() ;
}
```

The browser (I'm using Chrome) insist in rendering the page in between the asynchronous `DOM_manipulation_x` functions.

But this doesn't look nice. All the user sees is how the GUI changes in several steps for a fraction of a second.

Is it possible to instruct the browser somehow to stop rendering the page during this process?

Comment: @Andy, It's difficult to give a working example of the problem. I would have to post too much code. The question is simple though. Does the browser provide a mechanism to control when to render the page?

Comment: I'm just adding child elements to a parent container and setting some class names.

Comment: Yes. Doing the DOM manipulations in a new disconnected/hidden element and then replacing the old element with the new one. Thus avoiding the intermediate reflows. But the question I'm asking is different and much simpler. Does the browser allow the developer to decide when to update the viewport or we are stuck with the automated decisions made by the browser and we have to work around them. I vaguely remember having read something about an API to do this. That's why I asked the question.

Answer (score 0):

I think, according to my tests, this is not possible. The only one way I can see is to prepare a batch of updates into some internal structure and update the DOM at once when all async operations ends.

so the (TypeScript) code can look something like

```
interface DOMOperation {
   node: Node,
   operation: (...args: any) => void;
   args: any[];
}

export class DOMBatch {

   private queue: DOMOperation[] = [];
   private updateRunning: boolean = false;

   public async beginUpdate(): Promise<void> {

      return new Promise(

         (resolve) => {

            const checkUpdateRunning = () => {
               if (this.updateRunning) {
                  setTimeout(() => { checkUpdateRunning() }, 0); // each new JavaScript loop check if the update is running
               } else {
                  this.queue = [];
                  resolve();
               }
            }

            checkUpdateRunning();

         }

      )

   }

   public endUpdate() {

      for(const op of this.queue) {
         op.operation.apply(op.node, op.args);
      }

      this.updateRunning = false;

   }

   public appendChild(target: Node, childNode: Node) {
      this.queue.push({ node: target, operation: target.appendChild, args: [ childNode ] });
   }

   public removeChild(target: Node, childNode: Node) {
      this.queue.push({ node: target, operation: target.removeChild, args: [ childNode ]});
   }

   public insertBefore(target: Node, toInsert: Node, before: Node) {
      this.queue.push({ node: target, operation: target.insertBefore, args: [ toInsert, before ] });
   }

   public setAttribute(target: Element, name: string, value: string) {
      this.queue.push({ node: target, operation: target.setAttribute, args: [ name, value] });
   }

   public removeAttribute(target: Element, name: string) {
      this.queue.push({ node: target, operation: target.attributes.removeNamedItem, args: [ name ] });
   }


}

...
const domBatch = new DOMBatch();
...

async function async_DOM_manipulations(): Promise<void> {
    await domBatch.beginUpdate(); // cleanup the queue and wait for other possible renders running
    await prepare_DOM_manipulation_1(); // fill the batch with updates
    await prepare_DOM_manipulation_2(); // fill the batch with updates
    await prepare_DOM_manipulation_3(); // fill the batch with updates
    domBatch.endUpdate(); // render the batch
}
```

It must be ensured that another asynchronous DOM manipulation is not done in between of async tasks and final updateDOM so calls to beginUpdate() should return promise